# How to integrate: $\int _{-1}^1\left(4x+1\right)\sin \left(x^2+x\right)\cos \left(x^2\right)dx\:$

Tags: calculus

$$\int _{-1}^1\left(4x+1\right)\sin \left(x^2+x\right)\cos \left(x^2\right)dx\:$$

This was the last question on my calculus final. Although it is useless to know how to do it now, I want to understand the strategies involved for my own personal knowledge. Any hints or help are greatly apprecaited!

Comment: expand $\sin(x^2 +x)$ and then use $2 \sin x^2 \cos x^2 = \sin 2 x^2$

Answer (score 3):

When we have product of [Sinusoidal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) function, usage of [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) is probably the best option to start with

Here we have

$$2\sin(x^2+x)\cos(x^2)=\sin(2x^2+x)+\sin x$$

What is $\displaystyle\frac{d(2x^2+x)}{dx}=?$

For $\displaystyle\int(4x+1)\sin x\ dx$ use [LIATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule) rule Integration by Parts setting $4x+1$  as the first term

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. Basic trig:
   $$ \sin a \cos b = 0.5[\sin(a+b) + \sin(a-b)] $$
2. Variable change:
   $$ y = 2x^2 + x, \; dy = (4x+1)dx$$
3. Integration by parts:
   $$ \int x\sin x dx = -\int x (\cos x)' dx$$
4. Linearity of integral at every step.

Basically all strategies you've learned for integrals (unleashed only after the trig formula was used).